# How can I start my Topshelf service after installation?

Tags: c#, windows-services, topshelf

I have a Topshelf service that is working great. It installs with Automatic startup and I can start/stop the service just fine. My problem is that the service requires a user to start it initially.

Is there a standard way of starting the service immediately after installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimally, run the service from the command line with the `start` verb after it has been installed, e.g.,

```
.\MyService.exe start
```

Note that you'll probably want to do this from a command prompt running in administrative mode, which is consistent with how you typically install software on Windows systems.  For more discussion, see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206738/installing-a-topshelf-application-as-a-windows-service/36283936#36283936).

Refer to the command line documentation [here](http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/overview/commandline.html) for other helpful commands.