# How to install Topshelf.Runtime.Windows.WindowsHostSettings service

Tags: c#, .net, service, window

I'm trying to run a service in my local and this is what I get from the error log.[image: Error Log]

I tried searching on how to install the service but there are none that show on how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

I think [these answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206738/installing-a-topshelf-application-as-a-windows-service) can answer your question.

But basically, first you need to install your service using

```
your_service.exe install
```

And then, you can start it using

```
your_service.exe start
```

[More command line options here](http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/overview/commandline.html)