How to build 24*7 working solution in .NET
I have a scenario. I have a folder called Test. When a new pdf is added to this folder, I want to print it and delete it from that folder after print. For this, I have developed a console application in .NET, where I am using FileSystemWatcher to this Test folder and printing and deleting it.
But I have a confusion about how to release it for usage. It should listen all the time for new file-added events. How to achieve this.
Currently, for development side, I have created a console application. I am running that exe and it will open a terminal and listen for new event.

Look at creating a Windows Service  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service

Sounds like you want to build a Windows Service. There is a library called "TopShelf" that is popular for this. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206738/installing-a-topshelf-application-as-a-windows-service

Seems like you want to deploy it on few systems around you as a quick solution.
Consider using windows task scheduler for such activity, you can create a task scheduler in windows, selecting trigger as "On Startup".
Go to Task Scheduler -> Create Task -> Trigger -> New -> select "Begin the task" as  "At Startup".

Release process is quite complex. But, simplifying, it at least consists of two steps:

building binary file to use (whether it's executable .exe for some users, or .dll library for other devs)
shipping to end users (installing on end users machines if app is on-prem, deploying to cloud, if app is cloud native, publishing to nuget source, if it's a nuget)

In your case, we have application that would need to run on end users' machines, and so it is on-premises app.
For such application to work, end user must download executable file (with your program) or installer that will install your app on user's machine.
For simplicity I would go with publishing executable file. Installer creation is different matter (but you can explore it).
So, after all, we clarified release process in your case:

you need to publish your executable with Visual Studio (right click the project, click Publish...) - this will build your code with release configuration (will apply code optimizations, etc.)
now you need to pack published folder with executable into ZIP and share with your end users - end user would just need to unpack the executable and run the application

What applicaiton type - console or windows service
This depends - if your users are fine with starting the app when THEY WANT, not to start it "automagically", I would stay with console app, which would be easy.
If users do not want to startup the app and expect it to be working out of the box - this is argument for Windows Service. Do not worry, your entire code will stay as is you just need to create different type of app and set it up differently.
References:

Tutorial: Publish a .NET console application using Visual Studio
SO post: Scheduled console app vs Windows service? When is it appropriate to use each
Tutorial: Create a Windows service app
Create Windows Service using BackgroundService
How to Create and Deploy Windows Services

